# Format RTF text into multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf, activereports

I have a richtextbox on my wpf form that the user types into, with no restrictions on length. However, on my active reports output, I have pages with fixed-space textboxes on each page. Is there any way to figure out how much of the rich text will fit into a textbox, write it out, and then continue writing the rest on the next page until i run out of text to write?

Comment: Not really the question but you could format the text to a FlowDocument and display using a FlowDocumentPageViewer.

Comment: I need a way of sending the data being printed on each page to my active report so that it can be printed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the length of plain text on an ActiveReports Page using the Page object's MeasureText method. See the following documentation: http://www.datadynamics.com/help/activereports6/ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Page~MeasureText.html

If you have RTF output (I'm not sure if you do or not based on the information provided) it is probably not feasible to manually measure the text and break it up simply because RTF text is complex and breaking into parts is more difficult. However, the RichEdit/RTF control in ActiveReports should be able to paginate/page break it fine if you can let that control grow.

Comment: that is exactly my issue: I want to keep the formatting, but I can't let it grow arbitrarily. I have a set amount of space on each page to print in.

Comment: In ActiveReports 6 you cannot measure and reflow RTF manually like you can plain text. It's just really complicated to do. The rich edit control will automatically page-break RTF for you, but only on page boundaries, you cannot define an arbitrary boundary within a page. However, in ActiveReports 7 (coming very soon) they are working on some things that might help you here. I encourage you to contact the Product Management team to get in on the early private betas of that. To get in on the beta contact James Johnson at  james dot johnson at grapecity dot com.